# Proving a modulo statement

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> If the statement is true, then prove it, otherwise provide a counter example.
>
> If $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $x = y^2$, then $x\equiv y \pmod 2$

Could someone just check to see if my proof is correct or that i made a mistake somewhere. Thank you.

Proof: Counter Example. There exists $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $x=y^2$, then
$x \not \equiv y \pmod 2$. Let $x$ equal $3$, then $y^2$ equals $9$. Because you cannot divide $9$ by $2$, the statement $x \equiv y \pmod2$ is false. $3 \not \equiv 3 \pmod2$.

Comment: Why do you think that $9\not \equiv 3\pmod 2$? -- In fact, if you take $x=3$ and leave $y$ unspecified while assuming $x=y^2$, why do you think that $y^2=9$?

Comment: You've misunderstood the definition of the relation $x \equiv y \pmod n$.  You're asserting that $n \not\mid y$, which is true but not relevant. You need to decide if $n \mid (x-y)$, as Siong Thye Goh notes.

Comment: Congruence modulo two is just a question of parity (evenness or oddness). Two things are $\equiv\pmod2$ if and only if they have the same parity: both are even or both are odd. Given that outlook I think you can answer the question in a handful of words.

Answer (score 3):

If $x=9$ and $y=3$, we actually have $9 \equiv 3 \pmod2$ because we can divide $9\color{red}{-3}$  by $2$.

Try to check that if you square a number, you do not change the parity. If you square an odd number, you get an odd number. If you square an even number, you get an even number.

Comment: This is the answer I would have given. Plus one.

Comment: So the statement is true. Meaning we have to provide a proof to show that its true for any value ?

Comment: yes, the statement is true and a proof would be awesome.

Answer (score 1):

We essentially need $y(y-1)$ to be divisible by $2$

which is obvious as the product of two consecutive integers  is always even.

More generally, we can prove $$y^n\equiv y\pmod2$$